# How to find all objects of a type on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to iterate through all the objects in the stage and I'm not sure how to do it. 
   It's kind of improvised through my previous experience with C# and javascript.

1. First I need the correct list/array with all the stages children.
2. I need to check their type. I have a special custom class which extends Sprite with some additional properties only.

Someone proficient in actionscript 3.0 who can show the proper way to do?

```
for(var obj:DisplayObject in DisplayObjectContainer) {
    if(typeof obj == "Pic") {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest would be to use the "is" operator to accertain the object's class.

An example:

```
for( var i:int = stage.numChildren - 1; i>=0; i-- ) {
    if( stage.getChildAt(i) is Pic ) {
        // Do stuff with members of Pic class
```

Comment: `var obj:DisplayObject in DisplayObjectContainer` will only work if the DisplayObjectContainer is an array or vector. Otherwise frankhermes' way of finding the children of a displayObject is the way to go

Comment: @Daniel You are completely right. I mistakenly used OPs loop, not realizing it didn't work. It should work now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get to the children of a DisplayObjectContainer like that. You might need to do this:

```
for(var i=0;i<container.numChildren;i++)
{
     if(container.getChildAt(i) is Pic) doSomething();
}
```

where container is a DisplayObjectContainer.